# redirecting with a query isnt working - htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

When I attempt a redirect using normal text for the url it works fine...

```
Redirect 301 /thisisatest/ http://www.mydomain.com/test-result/
```

But when I try to use a url like this it does not work, I have pinpointed the problem down to the query ?...

```
Redirect 301 /sub.php?page=1&panel=1/ http://www.mydomain.com/test-result/
```

Is there something I should be including?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you cannot match QUEY_STRING in `Redirect` directive. You need to use `mod_rewrite` rule like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1&panel=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub\.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/test-result/? [L,R=301,NC]
```